# Is it possible to reposition the Cognigy WebChat toggle button in an <li> tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, togglebutton

I have the following test code, but no matter what I do the toggle button always positions itself to the bottom right of the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TestWebsite</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li>
        <script src="https://github.com/Cognigy/WebchatWidget/releases/latest/download/webchat.js"></script>
        <script>
            initWebchat(
                "https://endpoint-trial.cognigy.ai/1344d45dff864bfb0627d205f7f8835026ab24d0d27384ffabd4740a9c1023b2"
            )
        </script>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

I need it to be positioned in an `<li>` after `<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>`

Comment: can u add the css too? so we can we what might be the issue. coz visual representation is always better

Comment: @DarkForest I am using the bootstrapcdn as you can see in the ```<head>```  and as for the toggle button it is being created via the initWebChat function in webchat.js which I believe adds the css to the button.